# User stripe to payout to customer account automatically

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I use node.js and try to develop a website allow seller and buyer to trade on it.

I plan to use stripe as the way to pay to the website. When the buyer confirmed the product which seller send. I will payout the money to the seller.

I try to find guild in stripe docs but I only see the payout to account of yourself.

Is there someway allow stripe account to pay directly to other's bank account?

Comment: There's [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) to payout money to merchant account but it doesn't seem to fit into your use case. Consider using another payment gateway.

Comment: As glinda said, you can create Stripe connect accounts for your sellers and pay out to them later[1]. If you want to wait on your own verification, you will want to use separate charges and transfers[2] to allow yourself to hold the funds until you have confirmed what you need to. If you are unsure about Stripe Connect's fit for your business case, I'd reach out to Stripe support 

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers
[3] https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Comment: Thanks Glinda! Thanks Pompey! I will try to read the doc. If I can not fix it , I will try to use Paypal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.